# How to connect to wifi using Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter, for an acer v3 772g machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless, atheros

I am trying to connect to wifi using Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter, for an acer v3 772g machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

According to `lspci -nn` there is this card installed:
`Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)`

However, I have not been successful to connect to wifi on campus, but I can do so at home. Could you please kindly provide suggestions to troubleshoot this problem?

I tried

```
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

adding options `ath9k nohwcrypt=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf`

removing `system-ca-certs=true` from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/mySSIDname`

I also tried

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

I download the latest stable https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.18.1/backports-3.18.1-1.tar.gz

```
tar -zxvf  backports-3.18.1-1.tar.gz
cd ~/soft/backports-*/
make defconfig-ath9k
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r ath9k && sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Do you have any suggestion? Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ndiswrapper. You must have the Windows driver and see if that works.